# DomainFronting - re-routing and SSL certificats

Tags: certificates, malware, obfuscation, domain, cdn

I'm looking for a specific answer regarding the TLS handshake in a scenario of domain-fronting.
Following [hensonsecurity](https://hensonsecuritytools.wordpress.com/2019/11/02/how-domain-fronting-attacks-work-explained-in-seven-steps/) and [zscaler](https://www.zscaler.com/blogs/security-research/analysis-domain-fronting-technique-abuse-and-hiding-cdns) blogs I have noticed that a detailed description **regarding the re-direct / routing scheme is missing when the CDN finishes the legitimate TLS hand-shake and it sees that the GET is to another domain that hosted in it.
If there is a redirect command, is there a new ssl hand-shake with the domain itself (if it has imported its own private cert?)**

Comment: There is no redirect command or new ssl handshake.  See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/185194/how-does-domain-fronting-work-in-practice/270322#270322 for a working example that illustrates how domain fronting works, using openssl.

Answer (score 0):

Domain fronting works be misusing request routing implementation inside a CDN, which is responsible both for the outer domain O and inner domain I. With domain fronting the attacker uses the outer domain O as server name inside the TLS handshake (SNI extension), but uses the inner domain I as Host header inside the HTTP request inside the TLS connection. A passive deep packet inspection sees only the outer domain O and not the inner domain I. If the outer domain is acceptable the request will not be blocked by a DPI, even if the inner domain would be considered suspicious.

No additional TLS sessions and no redirects are involved here.

Comment: That I understand, but what happens when the domain inside the host got its own cert?

Comment: @user281868: This does not matter, i.e. the cert is not used since the TLS connection is done for a different domain on the same server.

Answer (score 0):

With domain fronting you use a "modified client", not a normal web browser or https library. This modified client makes the outer HTTPS to bear one destination, even though internally it is directed to someone else.